# Parsing JSON in UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I am new to iOS. i have to parse following JSON and display it to UITableViewCell. individual array is appearing in cell when i parse and append country item only. but all arrays for ex. rank ,country , population , flag are not appearing in cell.

how to add all rank , country , population , flag in array and put all them in cell. i have taken all them into string and then into array. and whole array i appended to main array.

following is JSON -

```
 http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt
```

code

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  {               
      NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webdata options:0 error:nil];                  
      NSArray *arrayWorldPopulation = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"worldpopulation"];
      for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayWorldPopulation) 
       {
           NSString *country = [diction objectForKey:@"country"];
           NSString *population = [diction objectForKey:@"population"];
           NSString *flag = [diction objectForKey:@"flag"];

           NSArray *temparray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:rank,country,population,flag, nil];
           [array addObject:temparray];   
       }
      [maintableView reloadData];
  }
```

Comment: And what's the code of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and the other ones of the datasource of your tableView?

Comment: Basically, you need to learn how to code cellForRowAtIndexPath.  It's non-trivial, and no one is going to do  your homework for you.  Hit the books!

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you need to implement tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: and tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath in your view controller.  This tells the table how many rows to expect and what each row in the table looks like.  The simple code below assumes you have an array of strings and are just displaying one string per cell and should get you started.  Your specific situation sounds like it may require a custom cell design.  [This tutorial describes how to do this in a storyboard with a custom cell class](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1).

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section        
{
    return [array count]; //tell the UITableView how many are items are in the array
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     //stuff to make sure iOS is reusing cells rather than creating new ones
     static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
     }

     NSString *itemFromArray = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //get the item for that cell

     cell.textLabel.text = itemFromArray; set the cell to display the text
     return cell;
}
```